# iOS8 black screen before splash screen on URL app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

This bug can be reproduced using the soundcloud app.

1. download the soundcloud app onto an ios8 device and launch the app
2. minimize the app by pressing the home button and launch safari
3. google search "soundcloud hardwell"
4. click on a search result that will send you to soundcloud.com
5. at the top of the page should be a button "Listen on SoundCloud iOS", click it
6. as safari transitions to the soundcloud app there will be a few seconds where the soundcloud splash screen is not visible and will just appear as a black screen

currently I am experiencing a similar problem with my app. The app currently uses image assets for splash screens and i dont not experience the above UI bug. However in attempts to support iPad pro ive removed the image assests and am instead using a splash screen .xib file. Using the .xib splash screen file causes the black screen to appear only on iOS8. Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it is?

Edit:
The twitter app also suffers from the bug mentioned above. This appears to be a bug in ios8?

Comment: Does it happen in every app? Might be an iOS8 bug.

Comment: No not every app. from testing it appears to happen in all configurations of setting a splash launch screen. The only configuration to work without the UI bug is if only image assets are used